# CSS box-shadow or normal image file for a pixel art?

Tags: css, image, performance, pixel

So I want to use some pixel arts in my web app. I was using a normal image file (`.png`) for my pixel art and import it through `<img>` tag or through `background-image` property.

But then I discovered this [site](https://www.pixelartcss.com/), it allows me to draw a pixel art then convert it to css using `box-shadow` property. This makes me wonder which one will produce a better performance for my app, the original way or the `box-shadow` way?

Can you give me some advantages and disadvantages of each way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, avoiding server round-trips to fetch additional files is a good idea if you want to improve speed and performance.

If you are downloading

- a **CSS file**
- a **PNG**

and you have the option to download *only* the **CSS file**, then that's a good option to consider.

---

You can hardcode utility graphics into your CSS files using the following techniques:

1. Encode the `.png` using **Base 64 Encoding** and declare `background-image` referencing a Data URI describing the `.png`
2. Use an `.svg` instead and declare `background-image` referencing a Data URI describing the `.svg` (no need to base-64 encode this time, since SVGs are already text-based)
3. Use the `box-shadow` technique referenced in your question

There may be further techniques for hardcoding utility graphics into your CSS files.

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Encoding_data_into_base64_format